# Laravel deploying error " domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" using FTP

Tags: laravel, ftp, deploying

I have develop a laravel 5.2 app with database. when i upload everthing to the server using FTP and trying to access it. it gives me an error of

> " mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR
>   500".

i copy the whole project to my public_html/myproject. when i'm accessing it with mydomain.com/myproject/public/ the error pops out. what should i do? do i have to configure anything? if there is, what is it?. Thanks. and also i already have database in my server.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your .env file [accordingly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration), with the right access to your server database. It would look something like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=*my_server_database*
DB_USERNAME=*my_username*
DB_PASSWORD=*my_password*
```

Comment: Yeah. I actually configured that already. but still give me that error.

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: where's the log located?

Comment: I don't think this will help but here it is `#57 C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\laravel_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 C:\xampp\htdocs\sitefolder\laravel_project\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 {main}` i believe this is the log from my local host. not on live.